# new object with async routines

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, co

I want to instantiate an object where the constructor performs async calls before returning. The purpose is to do async currying. I am using [co](https://github.com/tj/co). The below example fails. What am I doing wrong?

```js
var co = require('co')

function asyncFunction() { 
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    resolve()    
  })
}

function MyObject () {
  co(function * () {
    yield asyncFunction()
  }).then(()=> {
    this.runSomething = function() {
      return 'something'
    }
  })
}

new MyObject().runSomething()
// TypeError: (intermediate value).runSomething is not a function
```

Comment: `co` returns a `Promise`, that you don't resolve.

Comment: When you see a pure dot notation sequence of properties without any callback (lke `new MyObject().runSomething()`), it is synchronous. You need a callback in the main code.

Comment: Don't do it! Allow `new MyObject()` to be wholly synchronous and relegate anything async to method(s) of MyObject().

Comment: That's what I've done @Roamer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `new` operator will always return an object immediately, and synchronously. You can't delay that operation.

You could instead create a function that will return a Promise for your object.

```
function makeObjectAsync() {
  const asyncResult = asyncOperation();
  return asyncResult.then(result => ({
    runSomething() { /* ... */ }
  }));
}

myObjectAsync()
  .then(obj => {
    // obj is ready to use.
    return obj.runSomething();
  });
```

You can combine that with `co` fairly easily to get read of some of the `.then()`s.

Comment: Thank you. I was suspecting this was the only path when using new.